# Angular2 создание объектов, ленивая подгрузка данных

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript, frontend, dependency-injection

Доброго времени суток, есть недопонимание работы с объектами.

Предположим что бэкенд возвращает json вида

```
{id: 1, login: 'Test', name: 'Test', email: 'test@test.ru', role_id: 1}
```

на выходе я хочу иметь объект, который так же хранит в себе объект роли, для этого опишу класс вида

```
import {Role} from './Role';
export class User {
    id: number;
    login: string;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    role_id: number;
    role: Role;
}
```

для заполнения свойства Role, я могу из сервиса отправить дополнительный запрос, но есть желание реализовать ленивую загрузку зависимостей объекта, чтоб не грузить их напрасно, а только по их необходимости.

Мой уровень знания angula2 (небольшой), логично говорит мне "засунь сервис в объект и запроси данные, при обращение к свойству".

```
import {Role} from './Role';
import {UsersService} from '../services/users.service';
export class User {
    id: number;
    login: string;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    role_id: number;
    private _role: Role = null;
    constructor(private usersService: UsersService) {
    }
    get role(): Role {
        if (this._role === null) {
            this.usersService.getRole(this.role_id).subscribe(
                role => {
                    this._role = role;
                }
            );
        }
        return this._role;
    }
}
```

К сожалению такой подход нарушает принципы DI ангуляра, так же я в итоге не смогу создать объект класса, ну либо каким то боком передавать в конструктор сервис. Документации на эту тему особо не нашел, все примеры крутятся вокруг непосредственно сервисов, есть небольшое упоминание того, что не рекомендуется создавать фабрики, а рекомендуется использоваться возможности DI и подгружать классы через конструктор, с указанием в провайдерах, но подгружать таким образом объекты мне кажется странным.

**Вопрос:** подскажите правильные статьи, либо расскажите каким образом правильно создавать объекты, как правильно реализовывать ленивую загрузку данных.

Comment: Роль нужно самому загружать тогда, когда это требуется. На пример если у вас есть страница с Юзером и там нужно получить название роли, то нужно загрузить юзера и в подписке загрузить роль.